# How to update two parameters using Ajax in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to update this helper function with Ajax:

```
def radio_buttons_collection(types, invoice_type)
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    content_tag :span, :class => "radio_option" do
      radio_button_tag("project[invoice_type]", type, type == invoice_type) + type
    end
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

However, I am having trouble getting the two parameters in there.

```
# get_invoice_types.js.erb:

$('#project_invoice_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(radio_buttons_collection(@types, @invoice_type)) %>");
```

---

```
# projects_controller.rb:

def get_invoice_types
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])
  @types = person.address_types

  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @invoice_type = project.invoice_type
end
```

---

```
# application.js:

$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

Can anybody help?

Right now, only the `@types` parameter gets passed properly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Helping with Anezio Campos:**

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {

    var person_id = $(this).val();
    var project_id = $("#project_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
        data: {person_id: person_id, id: project_id},
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

Try it, if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.val()')`

Comment: Same when I use `.value()` instead.

Comment: did you tried `var person_id = $("#project_person_id").val();` ?

Comment: actually it would me `$(this).val();` it's my mistake. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

On `projects#get_invoice_types` you are trying to get the project with:

```
project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

But you are not passing `id` in your ajax call, you are only passing `person_id`

You should also pass the `id` param in your ajax call

Add a hidden_field with id `project_id` and with the value of the project.id

Then

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
        data: 'person_id=' + this.value + '&id=' + $("#project_id").value(),
        dataType: 'script'
    })
});
```

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work. I am getting this strange error in my console which I haven't seen before: `Couldn't find Project with id=[object Object]` `app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:58:in get_invoice_types` Line 58 is this one in my case: `project = Project.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Try $("#project_id").value() in your ajax. My mistake.

Comment: Strange. Now I get this: `application.js:105TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#project_id").value()')`

Comment: OK, got this working in the end, thanks to you and *rony36*. Cheers!